# Navigating dropdown menu with touchstart for IOS functionality

Tags: javascript, ios, drop-down-menu, touchstart

I am using the following code to close a navigation sub menu when the page is touched outside the menu on IOS devices. The problem is when I touch a link within the menu it closes as well. My question is how can I prevent touching the navigation links within my sub menu from triggering the div from closing yet maintain that feature when elsewhere on the page is touched?

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function(){
 document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }, false)
  }, false)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4a4o0ctt/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted previous answer ;)

and created a fiddle for you in which you can find an event which fires only on body, not on the child elements. Take a look;
http://jsfiddle.net/7komnku9/

The most important part here is this code;

```
  if(e.target!== this)
        return;
```

I think you can follow this to get your event working as desired ;)

Comment: Well yes, safari on iOS afaik has some problems with "click" event. Use "touchstart" instead.

Comment: Yep, I tried the fiddle with my iPhone with changed event to "touchstart" - works.

Comment: fiddle2 is close but I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the alert with both the yellow wrapper as well as its children links.

Comment: just add must-click class to everything what should prevent the popup.
Like here; 
<div id="wrapper" class="must-click">